# My Android unit test never completes in Eclipse

Tags: android, unit-testing

When running a unit test (Run as Android JUnit test) it never completes. 
Output:

[2011-03-03 21:45:43 - TestMyProj] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554

[2011-03-03 21:45:43 - TestMyProj] Collecting test information

[2011-03-03 21:45:47 - TestMyProj] Sending test information to Eclipse

[2011-03-03 21:45:47 - TestMyProj] Running tests...

...and nothing more. 
Code:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

   public MainActivityTest() {
       super("my.app.MainActivity", MainActivity.class);
   }
   private MainActivity mActivity;
   @Override
   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
      super.setUp();
      mActivity = this.getActivity();
   }
   public void testOneEqualsOne() {
      assertEquals(1,1);
   }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Kind regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you are using is **deprecated**. This may not be the root cause of the problem but it might help.
Use:

```
   public MainActivityTest() {
       super(MainActivity.class);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look later.

Comment: The above only seems to be true for 2.2. I was using 2.1 and when changing the constructor without the first argument it didn't compile. Changing to 2.2 and the constructor above made the test run but the question remains why the test didn't run for 2.1.